# Measure resistance value between all nodes in a 3x3 resistor grid

Tags: arduino, resistors, resistance, measurement, voltage-measurement

I have a Schematic like that:
[image: Schematic]

(except the power supply is an Arduino Uno with a voltage divider to measure resistance between any pair of ABC and 123, except C3 of course)

How can I get the resistance between all nodes (the resistance of every single resistor) in the grid, when I only measure between ABC and 123? All resistors are unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd do it by setting up the equations and solving for the unknowns.

But in this case it's impossible.

The two resistors in the top left are in series, and there's no measurement point between them. That means that you can only get the combined resistance of the pair, with no way to separate it into its component resistances.

Comment: It's worse than that, actually. There are 12 resistors, but only 9 possible measurements. This is equivalent to trying to solve 9 equations with 12 unknowns. Not going to happen

Comment: Okay, thank you. Can you give me a link to where I can read more about setting up these equations, even when I get only a combined resistance of some resistors?

Comment: You'd better tell what task you are trying to solve :)
Perhaps there could be easier ways...

Comment: @pythonimus: They're just the standard serial, parallel, and delta-wye equations, used appropriately.

Comment: I have a grid like this (probably more rows/columns) with changing resistor values. I need a way to measure as many resistor values possible with as few connections to the grid as possible.

Comment: @pythonimus - Look up KCL and KVL (Kirchoff Current/Voltage Law).